# How construction np.subtract.outer(x, y) works?

Tags: python, numpy

I ran into a construction `np.subtract.outer(x, y)` while studying how to build covariance matrices. For example:

```
x=np.array([1.,2.])
y=np.array([3.0,4.0,5.0])
np.subtract.outer(x, y)
```

gives

```
array([[-2., -3., -4.],
       [-1., -2., -3.]])
```

How does this construction work? By "construction", I mean chaining of `subtract` and `outer`. And where can I read about it in the numpy documentation?

Comment: Do you mean how it is implemented? Have a look here: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.outer.html#numpy.ufunc.outer And in the example, replace ```op``` with subtract.

Comment: `subtract` is `ufunc`.  `outer` is a method of the function.  Think of it as a specialized way of applying `subtract` to the inputs.  It's not "chaining", The arguments come after the outer, not the `subtract`. `ufuncs` have a number such methods.  `x[:,None]-y` does the same thing, using the `-` operator and `broadcasting`.

Comment: Ah, OK, I didn't know that `ufunc`s are classes actually, not functions. Now it makes sense. Thanks!